# Is there a limit to the amount of tables in a MySQL database you can create at a time?

Tags: mysql

```html
#!/usr/bin/python

import MySQLdb as mdb
def datainit():
 con=mdb.connect('localhost','chemistrystudent', 'chem', 'thermochem');
 with con:
  cur=con.cursor()
  #Aluminum
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Aluminum(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Aluminum(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Al(s)',0,0,28.32)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Aluminum(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('AlCl3(s)',-705.6,-630.0,109.3)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Aluminum(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Al2O3(s)',-1669.8,-1576.5,51.00)")
  print "aluminum"
  # Barium
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Barium(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Barium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Ba(s)',0,0,63.2)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Barium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('BaCO3(s)',-1216.3,-1137.6,112.1)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Barium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('BaO(s)',-553.5,-525.1,70.42)")
  print "barium"
  # Beryllium
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Beryllium(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Beryllium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Be(s)',0,0,9.44)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Beryllium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('BeO(s)',-608.4,-579.1,13.77)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Beryllium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Be(OH)2(s)',-905.8,-817.9,50.21)")
  print "beryllium"
  # Bromine
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Bromine(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Bromine(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Br(g)',111.8,82.38,174.9)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Bromine(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Br-(aq)',-120.9,-102.8,80.71)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Bromine(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Br2(g)',30.71,3.14,245.3)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Bromine(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Br2(l)',0,0,152.3)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Bromine(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('HBr(g)',-36.23,-53.22,198.49)")
  print "Bromine"  
  # Calcium
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Calcium(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Calcium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Ca(g)',179.3,145.5,154.8)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Calcium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Ca(s)',0,0,41.4)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Calcium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('CaCO3(s,calcite)',-1207.1,-1128.76,92.88)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Calcium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('CaCl2(s)',-795.8,-748.1,104.6)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Calcium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('CaF2(s)',-1219.6,-1167.3,68.87)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Calcium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('CaO(s)',-635.5,-604.17,39.75)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Calcium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Ca(OH)2(s)',-986.2,-898.5,83.4)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Calcium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('CaSO4(s)',-1434.0,-1321.8,106.7)")
  print "Calcium"
  # Carbon
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Carbon(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Carbon(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('C(g)',718.4,672.9,158.0)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Carbon(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('C(s,diamond)',1.88,2.84,2.43)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Carbon(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('C(s,graphite)',0,0,5.69)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Carbon(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('CCl4(g)',-106.7,-64.0,309.4)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Carbon(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('CCl4(l)',-139.3,-68.6,214.4)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Carbon(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('CF4(g)',-679.9,-635.1,262.3)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Carbon(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('CH4(g)',-74.8,-50.8,186.3)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Carbon(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('C2H2(g)',226.77,209.2,200.8)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Carbon(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('C2H4(g)',52.30,68.11,219.4)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Carbon(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('C2H6(g)',-84.68,-32.89,229.5)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Carbon(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('C3H8(g)',-103.85,-23.47,269.9)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Carbon(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('C4H10(g)',-124.73,-15.71,310.0)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Carbon(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('C4H10(l)',-147.6,-15.0,231.0)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Carbon(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('C6H6(g)',82.9,129.7,269.2)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Carbon(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('C6H6(l)',49.0,124.5,172.8)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Carbon(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('CH3OH(g)',-201.2,-161.9,237.6)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Carbon(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('CH3OH(l)',-238.6,-166.23,126.8)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Carbon(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('C2H5OH(g)',-235.1,-168.5,282.7)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Carbon(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('C2H5OH(l)',-277.7,-174.76,160.7)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Carbon(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('C6H12O6(s)',-1273.02,-910.4,212.1)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Carbon(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('CO(g)',-110.5,-137.2,197.9)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Carbon(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('CO2(g)',-393.5,-394.4,213.6)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Carbon(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('CH3COOH(l)',-487.0,-392.4,159.8)")
  print "carbon"
  # Cesium
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Cesium(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cesium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Cs(g)',76.50,49.53,175.6)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cesium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Cs(l)',2.09,0.03,92.07)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cesium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Cs(s)',0,0,85.15)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cesium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('CsCl(s)',-442.8,-414.4,101.2)")
  print "cesium"
  # Chlorine
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Chlorine(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Chlorine(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Cl(g)',121.7,105.7,165.2)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Chlorine(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Cl(aq)',-167.2,-131.2,56.5)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Chlorine(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Cl2(g)',0,0,222.96)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Chlorine(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('HCl(aq)',-167.2,-131.2,56.5)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Chlorine(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('HCl(g)',-92.30,-95.27,186.69)")
  print "chlorine"
  # Chromium
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Chromium(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Chromium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Cr(g)',397.5,352.6,174.2)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Chromium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Cr(s)',0,0,23.6)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Chromium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Cr2O3(s)',-1139.7,-1058.1,81.2)")
  print "chromium"
  # Cobalt
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Cobalt(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cobalt(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Co(g)',439,393,179)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cobalt(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Co(s)',0,0,28.4)")
  print "cobalt"
  # Copper
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Copper(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Copper(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Cu(g)',338.4,298.6,166.3)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Copper(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Cu(s)',0,0,33.30)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Copper(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Cucl2(2)',-205.9,-161.7,108.1)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Copper(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('CuO(s)',-156.1,-128.3,42.59)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Copper(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Cu2O(s)',-170.7,-147.9,92.36)")
  print "copper"
  # Fluorine
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Fluorine(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Fluorine(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('F(g)',80.0,61.9,158.7)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Fluorine(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('F(aq)',-332.6,-278.8,-13.8)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Fluorine(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('F2(g)',0,0,202.7)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Fluorine(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('HF(g)',-268.61,270.70,173.51)")

  # Hydrogen
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Hydrogen(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Hydrogen(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('H(g)',217.94,203.26,114.60)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Hydrogen(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('H+(aq)',0,0,0)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Hydrogen(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('H+(g)',1536.2,1517.0,108.9)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Hydrogen(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('H2(g)',0,0,130.58)")


  # Iodine
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Iodine(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Iodine(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('I(g)',106.60,70.16,180.66)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Iodine(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('I-(aq)',-55.19,-51.57,111.3)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Iodine(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('I2(g)',62.25,19.37,260.57)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Iodine(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('I2(s)',0,0,116.73)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Iodine(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('HI(g)',25.94,1.30,206.3)")

  # Iron
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Iron(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Iron(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Fe(g)',415.5,369.8,180.5)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Iron(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Fe(s)',0,0,27.15)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Iron(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Fe2+(aq)',-87.86,-84.93,113.4)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Iron(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Fe3+(aq)',-47.69,-10.54,293.3)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Iron(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('FeCl2(s)',-341.8,-302.3,117.9)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Iron(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('FeCl3(s)',-400,-334,142.3)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Iron(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('FeO(s)',-271.9,-253.2,60.75)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Iron(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Fe2O3(s)',-822.16,-740.98,89.96)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Iron(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Fe3O4(s)',-1117.1,-1014.2,146.4)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Iron(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('FeS2(s)',-171.5,-160.1,52.92)")

  # Lead
  
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Lead(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Lead(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Pb(s)',0,0,68.85)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Lead(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('PbBr2(s)',-277.4,-260.7,161)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Lead(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('PbCO3(s)',-699.1,-625.5,131.0)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Lead(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Pb(NO3)2(aq)',-421.3,-246.9,303.3)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Lead(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Pb(NO3)2(s)',-451.9,0,)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Lead(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('PbO(s)',-217.3,-187.9,68.70)")
  
  # Lithium
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Lithium(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Lithium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Li(g)',159.3,126.6,138.8)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Lithium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Li(s)',0,0,29.09)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Lithium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Li+(aq)',-278.5,-273.4,12.2)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Lithium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Li+(g)',685.7,648.5,133.0)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Lithium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('LiCl(s)',-408.3,-384.0,59.30)")

  # Magnesium
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Magnesium(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Magnesium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Mg(g)',147.1,112.5,148.6)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Magnesium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Mg(s)',0,0,32.51)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Magnesium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('MgCl2(s)',-641.6,-592.1,89.6)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Magnesium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('MgO(s)',-601.8,-569.6,26.8)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Magnesium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Mg(OH)2(s)',-924.7,-833.7,63.24)")

  # Manganese
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Manganese(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Manganese(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Mn(g)',280.7,238.5,173.6)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Manganese(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Mn(s)',0,0,32.0)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Manganese(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('MnO(s)',-385.2,-362.9,59.7)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Manganese(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('MnO2(s)',-519.6,-464.8,53.14)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Manganese(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('MnO4(aq)',-541.4,-447.2,191.2)")

  # Mercury
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Mercury(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Mercury(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Hg(g)',60.83,31.76,174.89)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Mercury(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Hg(l)',0,0,77.40)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Mercury(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('HgCl2(s)',-230.1,-184.0,144.5)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Mercury(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Hg2Cl2(s)',-264.9,-210.5,192.5)")

  # Nickel
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Nickel(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Nickel(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Ni(g)',429.7,384.5,182.1)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Nickel(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Ni(s)',0,0,29.9)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Nickel(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('NiCl2(s)',-305.3,-259.0,97.65)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Nickel(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('NiO(s)',-239.7,-211.7,37.99)")

  # Nitrogen
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Nitrogen(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Nitrogen(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('N(g)',472.7,455.5,153.3)")
  print "nitrogen executed"   
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Nitrogen(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('N2(g)',0,0,191.50)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Nitrogen(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('NH3(aq)',-80.29,-26.50,111.3)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Nitrogen(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('NH3(g)',-46.19,-16.66,192.5)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Nitrogen(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('NH4+(aq)',-132.5,-79.31,113.4)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Nitrogen(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('N2H4(g)',95.40,159.4,238.5)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Nitrogen(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('NH4CN(s)',00,0,)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Nitrogen(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('NH4Cl(s)',-314.4,-203.0,94.6)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Nitrogen(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('NH4NO3(s)',-365.6,-184.0,151)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Nitrogen(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('NO(g)',90.37,86.71,210.62)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Nitrogen(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('NO2(g)',33.84,51.84,240.45)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Nitrogen(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('N2O(g)',81.6,103.59,220.0)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Nitrogen(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('N2O4(g)',9.66,98.28,304.3)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Nitrogen(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('NOCl(g)',52.6,66.3,264)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Nitrogen(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('HNO3(aq)',-206.6,-110.5,146)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Nitrogen(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('HNO3(g)',-134.3,-73.94,266.4)")
  


  # Oxygen
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Oxygen(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Oxygen(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('O(g)',247.5,230.1,161.0)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Oxygen(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('O2(g)',0,0,205.0)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Oxygen(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('O3(g)',142.3,163.4,237.6)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Oxygen(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('OH-(aq)',-230.0,-157.3,-10.7)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Oxygen(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('H2O(g)',-241.82,-228.57,188.83)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Oxygen(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('H2O(l)',-285.83,-237.13,69.91)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Oxygen(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('H2O2(g)',-136.10,-105.48,232.9)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Oxygen(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('H2O2(l)',-187.8,-120.4,109.6)")

  # Phosphorus
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Phosphorus(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Phosphorus(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('P(g)',316.4,280.0,163.2)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Phosphorus(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('P2(g)',144.3,103.7,218.1)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Phosphorus(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('P4(g)',58.9,24.4,280)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Phosphorus(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('P4(s,red)',-17.46,-12.03,22.85)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Phosphorus(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('P4(s,white)',0,0,41.08)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Phosphorus(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('PCl3(g)',-288.07,-269.6,311.7)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Phosphorus(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('PCl3(l)',-319.6,-272.4,217)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Phosphorus(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('PF5(g)',-1594.4,-1520.7,300.8)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Phosphorus(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('PH3(g)',5.4,13.4,210.2)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Phosphorus(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('P4O6(s)',-1640.1,,)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Phosphorus(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('P4O10(s)',-2940.1,-2675.2,228.9)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Phosphorus(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('POCl3(g)',-542.2,-502.5,325)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Phosphorus(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('POCl3(l)',-597.0,-520.9,222)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Phosphorus(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('H3PO4(aq)',-1288.3,-1142.6,158.2)")


  # Potassium
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Potassium(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Potassium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('K(g)',89.9,61.17,160.2)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Potassium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('K(s)',0,0,64.67)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Potassium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('KCl(s)',-435.9,-408.3,82.7)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Potassium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('KClO3(s)',-391.2,-289.9,143.0)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Potassium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('KClO3(aq)',-349.5,-284.9,265.7)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Potassium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('K2CO3(s)',-1150.18,-1064.58,155.44)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Potassium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('KNO3(s)',-492.70,-393.13,132.9)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Potassium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('K2O(s)',-363.2,-322.1,94.14)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Potassium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('KO2(s)',-284.5,-240.6,122.5)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Potassium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('K2O2(s)',-495.8,-429.8,113.0)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Potassium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('KOH(s)',-424.7,-378.9,78.91)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Potassium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('KOH(aq)',-482.4,-440.5,91.6)")


  # Rubidium
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Rubidium(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Rubidium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Rb(g)',85.8,55.8,170.0)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Rubidium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Rb(s)',0,0,76.78)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Rubidium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('RbCl(s)',-430.5,-412.0,92)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Rubidium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('RbClO3(s)',-392.4,-292.0,152)")
 

  # Scandium
  #cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Scandium")
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Scandium(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Scandium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Sc(g)',377.8,336.1,174.7)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Scandium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Sc(s)',0,0,34.6)")

  # Selenium
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Selenium(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Selenium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('H2Se(g)',29.7,15.9,219.0)")

  # Silicon
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Silicon(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Silicon(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Si(g)',368.2,323.9,167.8)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Silicon(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Si(s)',0,0,18.7)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Silicon(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('SiC(s)',-73.22,-70.85,16.61)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Silicon(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('SiCl4(l)',-640.1,-572.8,239.3)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Silicon(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('SiO2(s,quartz)',-910.9,-856.5,41.84)")


  # Silver
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Silver(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Silver(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Ag(s)',0,0,42.55)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Silver(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Ag+(aq)',105.90,77.11,73.93)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Silver(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('AgCl(s)',-127.0,-109.70,96.11)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Silver(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Ag2O(s)',-31.05,-11.20,121.3)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Silver(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('AgNO3(s)',-124.4,-33.41,140.9)")

  # Sodium
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Sodium(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Sodium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Na(g)',107.7,77.3,153.7)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Sodium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Na(s)',0,0,51.45)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Sodium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Na+(aq)',-240.1,-261.9,59.0)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Sodium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Na+(g)',609.3,574.3,148.0)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Sodium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('NaBr(aq)',-360.6,-364.7,141.00)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Sodium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('NaBr(s)',-361.4,-349.3,86.82)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Sodium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Na2CO3(s)',-1130.9,-1047.7,136.0)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Sodium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('NaCl(aq)',-407.1,-393.0,115.5)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Sodium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('NaCl(g)',-181.4,-201.3,229.8)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Sodium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('NaCl(s)',-410.9,-384.0,72.33)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Sodium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('NaHCO3(s)',-947.7,-851.8,102.1)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Sodium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('NaNO3(aq)',-446.2,-372.4,207)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Sodium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('NaNO3(s)',-467.9,-367.0,116.5)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Sodium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('NaOH(aq)',-469.6,-419.2,49.8)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Sodium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('NaOH(s)',-425.6,-379.5,64.46)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Sodium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Na2SO4(s)',-1387.1,-1270.2,149.6)")

  # Strontium
  #cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Strontium")
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Strontium(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Strontium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('SrO(s)',-592.0,-561.9,54.9)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Strontium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Sr(g)',164.4,110.0,164.6)")

  # Sulfur
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Sulfur(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Sulfur(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('S(s,rhombic)',0,0,31.88)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Sulfur(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('S8(g)',102.3,49.7,430.9)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Sulfur(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('SO2(g)',-296.9,-300.4,248.5)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Sulfur(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('SO3(g)',-395.2,-370.4,256.2)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Sulfur(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('SO42-(aq)',-909.3,-744.5,20.1)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Sulfur(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('SOCl2(l)',-245.6,,)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Sulfur(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('H2S(g)',-20.17,-33.01,205.6)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Sulfur(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('H2SO4(aq)',-909.3,-744.5,20.1)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Sulfur(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('H2SO4(l)',-814.0,-689.9,156.1)")

  # Titanium
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Titanium(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Titanium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Ti(g)',468,422,180.3)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Titanium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Ti(s)',0,0,30.76)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Titanium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('TiCl4(g)',-763.2,-726.8,354.9)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Titanium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('TiCl4(l)',-804.2,-728.1,221.9)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Titanium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('TiO2(s)',-944.7,-889.4,50.29)")


  # Vanadium
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Vanadium(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Vanadium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('V(g)',514.2,453.1,182.2)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Vanadium(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('V(s)',0,0,28.9)")

  # Zinc
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Zinc(Substance VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dH DOUBLE, dG DOUBLE, dS DOUBLE)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Zinc(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Zn(g)',130.7,95.2,160.9)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Zinc(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('Zn(s)',0,0,41.63)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Zinc(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('ZnCl2(s)',-415.1,-369.4,111.5)")
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO Zinc(Substance,dH,dG,dS) Values ('ZnO(s)',-348.0,-318.2,43.9)")
 
print "Has the database been initiated? y/n"
init=str(raw_input())
if init.lower()=="n":
 try:
  datainit()
 except mdb.Error,e:
  print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1])
 print "Initialized"
```

Hello,
I'm attempting to create a database of the standard enthalpies of formation, standard entropies of formation, and standard Gibbs free energy of formation for a variety of different substances.

The function datainit() is meant to create multiple tables of the aforementioned information for the compounds of various elements in the database called "thermochem". Unfortunately, when I execute the function, only the statements down to the one creating the table for Nitrogen seem to be executed. Strangely, the syntax for the statement after that appears to be correct. The most relevant section of code is located beneath the comment #Nitrogen.

I am new to MySQL and I've probably made a few obvious errors. Is the function not executing completely because I'm creating too many tables at a time?

Comment: If you're asking that question, it's likely that there's a problem with your design!

Comment: I haven't seen more than a few thousand tables in a single database.  But, usually, it is poor design to have lots of tables, especially when they all have the same set of columns.

Answer (score 1):

Have not seen this behaviour before but let me suggest an alternative: create one table called Element( id INT, name char(256) ) and Element_properties( element_id, ... ) with a foreign key to table Elements. Then you only have to create two tables and you can start populating both tables.